# Binding dynamically added elements in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to delete some list elements after dynamically adding them.

The idea is that you can update the list, and then after updating it you can click on a list item to delete it.

**Html:**

```
<p>Test</p>
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>Acura</li>
    <li>Audi</li>
    <li>BMW</li>
    <li>Cadillac</li>
    <li>Ferrari</li>
</ul>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" id="button">
```

**Javascript:**

```
var new_list =
    '<ul data-role="listview">' +
    '<li class="delete">Dog</li>' +
    '<li class="delete">Cat</li>' +
    '</ul>';

$('#button').off('click').on('click', function () {
    $('ul').remove();
    $('p').after(new_list);
    $('ul').listview();
});

$('.delete').off('click').on('click', function () {
    $( this ).remove();
});
```

## [**Jsfiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/WuvsB/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to bind events to dynamically added items is as follows.

```
$(document).on("event", ".selector", function () {
  $(this).remove();
  $('ul_selector').listview('refresh');
});
```