# JQM: Dynamically created button does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, button, dynamic

I'm creating an application with Phonegap using jQuery and jQuery Mobile (1.3.2). I simply haven't found a way to get a dynamically created button to work. I'm using an anchor as a button, so "button('refresh')" does nothing.

First I have a button defined in the HTML itself like this:

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right" id="addNewStep">Add a step</a>
```

Then I have Javascript that adds an action to that button like this:

```
$('#addNewStep').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    addStepDiv();
});
```

The button above WORKS and it creates a new ul-element which contains an anchor-button. That anchor button is the one I cannot get to work. It's a bit messy since I have some styling options. The multiline string works, since the whole element is displayed. addStepDiv():

```
function addStepDiv() {
    stepDiv = '<ul class="newStepList containerBox" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-dividertheme="a"> \
    <li data-role="list-divider" data-dividertheme="a"> \
        <span style="float: left; margin-top: 7px;">Title</span> \
        <a data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="delStepButton"></a> \
        <br style="clear: both;" /> \
    </li> \
        <li>Text</li> \
    </ul>';

    // Adds the above div under the "Add a step" -button
    $('#addNewStep').parent().append(stepDiv).trigger('create');
}
```

The delete button is supposed to do something. For now I've put in an alert just to see if the button is working. No alert is displayed.

```
$('.delStepButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    alert("Delete button");
});
```

Everything else works. The "Add step" -button creates the ul-element and it is displayed correctly, and the "Delete" -button is displayed as well, but nothing happens when clicking it.

//EDIT:
I feel like a total idiot... Thank you very much for your answers (Sridhar R & JCabello).
Problem fixed with:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delStepButton', function (e) {
    //Do stuff here.
});
```

Comment: delegation is the keyword, you should delegate event to the closest static container

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding dynamically added elements in jQuery mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431392/binding-dynamically-added-elements-in-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `.delStepButton` element are created dynamically you need to use event delegation to register event handlers to these elements.

When you use `$('.delStepButton').click(....);` to register an event handler it will register the handle to only those elements which are already present in the dom at the time of the code execution, in you case since these elements are created after that the handlers will not get attached to the newly created elements

Try with this

```
$(document).on('click','.delStepButton',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert("Moi");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach the listener to the document, instead of the item itself, since it doesn't exist at the moment you put the listener.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delStepButton', function (e) {
    //Do stuff here.
});
```