# cloned close button not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Im cloning some form elements, they are wrapped in a containing div. The 'close' button works the first time, but not on other cloned form sections.

//cloning code

```
function newObservation() {
    var len = $('.observation').length;
    var titleLen = $('.observation').length + 2;
    var $html = $('.observationTemplate').clone();

    $('.observationTitle:eq(0)').text("Observation - " + titleLen);
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-category]')[0].name = "audit-observation-category" + len;
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-notes]')[0].name = "audit-observation-notes" + len;
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-recommendation]')[0].name = "audit-observation-recommendation" + len;
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-severity]')[0].name = "audit-observation-severity" + len;
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-person]')[0].name = "audit-observation-person" + len;
    $html.find('[name=audit-observation-date]')[0].name = "audit-observation-date" + len;

    return $html.html();
}
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
    $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'observation',
        html: newObservation()
    }).appendTo('#auditContainer');

    $('#auditObservationButton').click(function () {
        $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'observation',
            html: newObservation()
        }).hide().appendTo('#auditContainer').slideDown('slow');
    });
    $('.observation').on('click', '.close', function () {
        $(this).closest('.observation').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

//HTML

```
            <div class="observationTemplate">
                <h4 class="observationTitle">Observation - 1</h4>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" class="close">close</a>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="audit-observation-category" class="ui-hidden-accessible select">Observation Category</label>
                    <select name="audit-observation-category" id="audit-observation-category" data-theme="e" data-corners="false">
                        <option value="" selected>Observation Category</option>
                        <option value="Site">Site</option>
                        <option value="Incident">Incident</option>
                        <option value="NearMiss">Near Miss</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label class="ui-hidden-accessible" for="audit-observation-notes">Notes</label>
                    <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="audit-observation-notes" id="audit-observation-notes" class="notes" placeholder="Notes" maxlength="140"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label class="ui-hidden-accessible" for="audit-observation-recommendation">Recommendation</label>
                    <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="audit-observation-recommendation" id="audit-observation-recommendation" class="notes" placeholder="Recommendation" maxlength="140"></textarea>
                </div>
                <!-- not working for some reason -->
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="audit-observation-severity" data-theme="e">Severity</label>
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <input type="range" name="audit-observation-severity" id="audit-observation-severity" value="15" min="15" max="180" step="15" data-hilight="true" data-theme="d">
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="audit-observation-person" class="ui-hidden-accessible select">Observation Person</label>
                    <select name="audit-observation-person" id="audit-observation-person" data-theme="e" data-corners="false">
                        <option value="" selected>Observation Person</option>
                        <option value="Jim">Jim</option>
                        <option value="Bob">Bob</option>
                        <option value="Gary">Gary</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                 <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label class="ui-hidden-accessible" for="audit-observation-date">Date</label>
                    <input type="date" name="audit-observation-date" id="audit-observation-date" placeholder="Date" value="">
                </div>
            </div><!--/observation-->

            <div id="auditContainer"></div>

            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-theme="d">
                <a href="#" id="auditObservationButton" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Add Observation</a>
            </div>
```

it isn't binding to the subsuqently created form sections. Any ideas?

Comment: Lets see the cloning code ans the html

Comment: if the `observation` element is cloned then your delegation code is wrong it should be `$(document).on('click', '.observation .close', function(){..});`

Comment: You realize that `closest()` starts whith the current element, so `$(this).closest('.observation')` is, well, `$(this)` ?

Comment: Also, use `.clone(true);`

Comment: .clone(true)? do not follow

Comment: Read the DOCS, it clones events and data

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! You're returning a string, not actual objects, never mind me then, delegation it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding dynamically added elements in jQuery mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431392/binding-dynamically-added-elements-in-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the jQuery on documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.

You therefore should be calling `on` on an element that will contain all your `.observation` elements.  In this case, the parent of your original observation will do.

```
$('#auditContainer').on('click', '.close', function(){
        //your code here
});
```

Comment: Excellent, was not going up high enough in the DOM. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try something like this:

```
function PageInit() {

  $('body').on({

      click: function () { $(this).closest('.observation').fadeOut(); }

  }, '.close');

}

$(PageInit)
```

;

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments the target `observation` elements are created dynamically in your case. In event delegation the event must be binded to an existing elements so you need to bind the click handler to the container element to which you are adding the `observation` elements

```
$('#auditContainer').on('click', '.observation .close', function(){
    $(this).closest('.observation').fadeOut();
});
```