# Jquery Mobile select Options menu[Phonegap Project]

Tags: jquery-mobile

I get informations about the product name , image, price, category etc from server  but i put the informations in a select menus and i want when i change the options of the select menu i display an alert success here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title></title>

</head>
 <body onLoad="Extra(); " >

            <div id="extra" >
            </div>          
    <script type="text/javascript" > 
        function Extra()
            {      

            var callData = JSON.stringify({"serviceName":"global_functions", "methodName":"getAcces","parameters":[]});
             $.post("http://www.test.com/webservice/?contentType=application/json", callData, function(data)
                     {
                $.each(data, function( index, value)
                    {                       
                    $("#extra").append('<div style="border:2px solid red" id="'+index+'"><h3>'+value["name"]+'</h3><img width="200px" src="http://www.test.com/'+value["image"]+'"><select class="comboextra" selected="selected" id="test'+index+'">');                        
                    $.each(value["items"],function(index1,value1)
                            { 
                        $("#test"+index).append('<option  prix="'+value1["prix"]+'"cat="'+value1["cat"]+'"  value= "'+value1["id"]+'" >"'+value1["name"]+'"</option>');

                            });
                    $("#extra").append('</select><label>Quantity</label><input type="number" name="q_extra1" value="0" id="q_extra1" class="quantiteextra" style="width:80px"></div><div class="alert alert-success icon-money"> valeur <span class="totalprix">0</span> </div>')
                    //alert("test");
                    }); 

                }); 

            }


         $(document).on("change", ".comboextra", function ()
                 {
              alert($(this).find(".comboextra option:selected").attr("prix"));               
              id = $(this).val(); 
              prix = $("option:selected", this).attr("prix")
              qte = $(".quantiteextra").val();
              acccat = $("option:selected", this).attr("cat");
              total = prix * qte;
              acccat = ($(this).find(".comboextra option:selected").attr("cat"));

             if (id != 0){$('#finaldata').find("[acccat="+acccat+"]").remove(); $("#finaldata").append('<input type="tex00t" acccat="'+acccat+'" id="acc'+id+'" name="acc['+id+']" value="'+qte+'">');} else {$('#finaldata').find("[acccat="+acccat+"]").remove();}
             $(this).find(".totalprix").html(total);

                 });

    </script>       

<body>       
</html>
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////EDITED AGAIN//////////////////////////////////

I can now display the alert and i want to select the product from the select menu and add the quantity and calculate the price here is my code after modification it's displaying the alert and the value =0 , it's not calculating and not displaying any value even when i change the quantity and when i change the product:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title></title>

</head>
<body onLoad="Extra(); " >

            <div id="extra" >
            </div>          

            <div id="finaldata"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" > 
        function Extra()
            {      

            var callData = JSON.stringify({"serviceName":"global_functions", "methodName":"getAcces","parameters":[]});
             $.post("http://www.test.com/webservice/?contentType=application/json", callData, function(data)
                     {
                $.each(data, function( index, value)
                    {                       
                    $("#extra").append('<div style="border:2px solid red" id="'+index+'"><h3>'+value["name"]+'</h3><img width="200px" src="http://www.test.com/'+value["image"]+'"><select class="comboextra" selected="selected" id="test'+index+'">');                        
                    $.each(value["items"],function(index1,value1)
                            { 
                        $("#test"+index).append('<option  prix="'+value1["prix"]+'"cat="'+value1["cat"]+'"  value= "'+value1["id"]+'" >"'+value1["name"]+'"</option>');

                            });
                    $("#extra").append('</select><label>Quantity</label><input type="number" name="q_extra1" value="0" id="q_extra1" class="quantiteextra" style="width:80px"></div><div class="alert alert-success icon-money"> valeur <span class="totalprix">0</span> </div>')
                    //alert("test");
                    }); 

                }); 

            }


         $(document).on("change", ".comboextra", function ()
                 {
              alert($(this).find(".comboextra option:selected").attr("prix"));               
              id = $(this).val(); 
              prix = $("option:selected", this).attr("prix")
              qte = $(".quantiteextra").val();
              acccat = $("option:selected", this).attr("cat");
              total = prix * qte;
              acccat = ($(this).find(".comboextra option:selected").attr("cat"));

             if (id != 0){$('#finaldata').find("[acccat="+acccat+"]").remove(); $("#finaldata").append('<input type="tex00t" acccat="'+acccat+'" id="acc'+id+'" name="acc['+id+']" value="'+qte+'">');} else {$('#finaldata').find("[acccat="+acccat+"]").remove();}
             $(this).find(".totalprix").html(total);

                 });

    </script>       

<body>       
</html>
```

Comment: i can't display the alert, thanks

Comment: because items are dynamically added, you should delegate `change` event `$(document).on("change", ".comboextra", function () { alert(); });`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding dynamically added elements in jQuery mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431392/binding-dynamically-added-elements-in-jquery-mobile)

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using jQM?

Comment: you want to show alert when loading options is done? or when an option is selected?

Comment: Thanks  it's working and i edited my post can you please help me with my problem.thanks

Comment: `id = $(this).val();` `prix = $("option:selected", this).attr("prix")`  `qte = $(".quantiteextra").val();` `acccat = $("option:selected", this).attr("cat");`

Comment: i add this alert inside the function alert($(this).find(".comboextra option:selected").attr("prix")); it shows me undefined , i also replaced my code with yours and it's not calculating anything and showing undefined.thanks

Comment: you can see i edit it again .thanks

Comment: `alert($(this).find(".comboextra option:selected").attr("prix"));` is wrong, `$(this)` = `$(".comboextra")` you are looking for `.comboextra` inside `.comboextra`.  dont use alert, use console.log for debugging. `console.log($("option:selected", this).attr("prix"));`

Comment: hello omar, can you please help me with this problem posted in this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930414/jquery-mobile-jquery-click-image-phonegap-project . thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should bind the `change` event when you have updated your document. Try adding the binding after you print the selects:

```
function Extra()
        {      
        var callData = JSON.stringify({"serviceName":"global_functions", "methodName":"getAcces","parameters":[]});
        $.post("http://www.test.com/webservice/?contentType=application/json", callData,
        function(data)
            {
                $.each(data, function( index, value)
                    {                       
                    $("#extra").append('<div style="border:2px solid red" id="'+index+'"><h3>'+value["name"]+'</h3><img width="200px" src="http://www.test.com/'+value["image"]+'"><select class="comboextra" selected="selected" id="test'+index+'">');                        
                    $.each(value["items"],function(index1,value1)
                        { 
                        $("#test"+index).append('<option  prix="'+value1["prix"]+'"cat="'+value1["cat"]+'"  value= "'+value1["id"]+'" >"'+value1["name"]+'"</option>');
                        });
                    $("#extra").append('</select><label>Quantity</label><input type="number" name="q_extra1" value="0" id="q_extra1" class="quantiteextra" style="width:80px"></div><div class="alert alert-success icon-money"> valeur <span class="totalprix">0</span> </div>')
                });  
                $(".comboextra").change(function()
                {
                    alert("success");               
                });
            });
        }
```